# Modeling Fog Formation Percentage with Exponential Decay Based on Dew Point Depression and Wind Speed

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-distribution, data-analysis

I am working with a 15-minute time series dataset that includes columns for Dew Point Depression and Wind Speed. Utilizing specific conditions based on these columns, I've successfully categorized fog formation into "dense," "moderate," and "light."

Now, I'm interested in creating a new column, which I'll call "Fog Formation Percentage." This column should quantify the extent of fog formation at each time point as a percentage. Given that fog tends to dissipate over time, I would like to model this fog formation percentage using an exponential decay function.

How can I go about implementing an exponential decay function to calculate the "Fog Formation Percentage" column? Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on:

- Formulating an exponential decay function that takes into account Dew
  Point Depression and Wind Speed.
- Determining the parameters within the decay function.
- Assigning the fog formation percentage values to the corresponding
  time points in my dataset.

Any advice or suggestions on the mathematical approach to achieve this, considering the temporal nature of fog formation, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!